# Can't insert spaces in my text input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form with 3 text inputs, the problem is, when I want to insert a space it doesn't allow me to. My code is:

```
<form action="post.php" name="MYFORM" id="MYFORM" method="post">
<label>Name</label>
<input name="name" size="30" type="text" id="name">
<br clear="all" />
<label>Email</label>
<input name="email" size="30" type="text" id="email">
<br clear="all" />
<label>Message</label>
<textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
<br clear="all" /><br clear="all" />
<label>&nbsp;</label>
<input value="Send" type="submit" id="Send">
```

When it submits it is validated by a javascript file and afterwards mailed by a php file, but I dont think that matters.

PROBLEM: cant add spaces in these text inputs.

Thanx in advance

EDIT: JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

 $('#Send').click(function() {  

        // name validation

        var nameVal = $("#name").val();
        if(nameVal == '') {

            $("#name_error").html('');
            $("#name").after('<div class="errorwrapper"><label class="error" id="name_error">Please enter your name.</label></div>');
            return false
        }
        else
        {
            $("#name_error").html('');
        }

        /// email validation

        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
        var emailaddressVal = $("#email").val();

        if(emailaddressVal == '') {
            $("#email_error").html('');
            $("#email").after('<div class="errorwrapper"><label class="error" id="email_error">Please enter your email address.</label></div>');
            return false
        }
        else if(!emailReg.test(emailaddressVal)) {
            $("#email_error").html('');
            $("#email").after('<div class="errorwrapper"><label class="error" id="email_error">Enter a valid email address.</label></div>');
            return false

        }
        else
        {
            $("#email_error").html('');
        }




            var mesVal = $("#message").val();
            if(mesVal == '') {

                $("#mes_error").html('');   
                $("#message").after('<div class="errorwrapper"><label class="error" id="mes_error">Please enter a message.</label></div>');
            }
            else
            {

            $("#after_submit").html('');
            $("#Send").after('<label class="success" id="after_submit">Your message has been submitted.</label>');
            $("#after_submit").fadeOut(9000);

            $("#mes_error").html('');


                clear_form();

            }   

    return false;
 })

 function clear_form()
 {
    $("#name").val('');
    $("#email").val('');
    $("#message").val('');
    $(".errorwrapper").empty();
 }
```

});

Comment: What javascript are you using to "validate" your form data?

Comment: did you purposely left out form end tag? ;)

Comment: Always include all relevant code. Adding spaces in the inputs at http://jsfiddle.net/HWepj/ works just fine.

Comment: Validate data on SERVER SIDE. Client side should be just a helper.

Comment: You haven’t specified what you mean by “cant add spaces in these text inputs”. Did your computer explode when you entered a space in an input box?

Comment: no just when you press the space button, it doesnt add a space in the box

Comment: @coderjoe, there is no such problem in @ohaal’s jsfiddle. You have not posted the part of the code causes your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have never figured it out if i wouldnt have seen an other person with an error in using a keyboard controlled javascript slideshow. Sry if i caused you guys wasting some time.

I was using fadeslideshow 2.0 by Pascal Bajorat.

Comment: Thanks. jquery.galleriffic by Trent Foley  ... No comments.